# Script with multiple curls that might timeout

Tags: bash, curl

I have a bash script that causes a few hundred cURL requests for data. While it is important for each cURL to be successful, it is arguably more important for the script (which runs multiple times an hour) to not be un-expectedly delayed because of an external server... so on each of the lines, is there something that can be used to set a max processing time to ensure one line doesn't delay the entire script?

some of the cURL are used to be included in calculations otherwise I would just put & at the end..  I want to find a way that a given line must be completed in less than X seconds or it kills the cURL and moves to the next line.

(and I can put in IF statements if values are empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--max-time <seconds>` argument to make sure that the curl command doesn't take more time than desired. From the [curl man page:](https://manpage.me/?q=curl)

> Maximum time in seconds that you allow the whole operation to take. 
>   This is useful for preventing your batch jobs from hanging for hours
>   due to slow networks or links going down.

Adding this argument to each curl command with a reasonable timeout for your problem should ensure that the whole script doesn't take too long.